# jquery determine element id by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

my html:

```
<a href="#" class="small button" id = "spare_approve_button_<?php echo $i; ?>">approve</a>
<a href="#" class="small button" id = "spare_return_button_<?php echo $i; ?>">return</a>
```

The buttons are created by a loop and I never know how many buttons I will have only that each will have a different id.

I would like to determine the id of the button that was clicked and I tried:

```
$("a.small.button").click(function(){
        var button_id = this.id;
        alert(button_id);
});
```

when a button is clicked, the alert doesn't even show so it seems it's not detecting my click. Firefox console shows no errors. Maybe `$("a.small.button")` is wrong, but what should it be?

Comment: @MarkWalters no. he's right in that part

Comment: Appears to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/VjENP/.

Comment: Are the buttons created in a loop client-side or server-side?

Comment: I bet its a late binding issue.

Comment: There must be no space here `id = " . . . "`. It should be `id=" . . . "`

Comment: @core1024 - that will make no difference whatsoever. See the [fiddle linked above](http://jsfiddle.net/VjENP/)

Comment: I apologize. I didn't know this. I learned something new :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your javascript code is executed too early. Try this :

```
$(function() {
    $("a.small.button").click(function(){
        var button_id = this.id;
        alert(button_id);
    });
});
```

If the buttons are created by javascript latter in the page, you must execute your code after that. Or you can use the `on` jQuery function on the parent of the buttons :

```
$(function() {
    // You can use a more specific parent.
    $(document).on('click', 'a.small.button' function() {
        var button_id = this.id;
        alert(button_id);
    });
});
```